# How to use REST library in Robot Framework?

Tags: rest, http, automated-tests, robotframework

Does anybody know how to use the REST Library for Robot Framework? The library is available here http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-restlibrary/source/browse/trunk/RestLibrary.py. It seems like there is no documentation available.

I tried something like this in Robot Framework but there is no response coming back from the request:

```
REST Test Case
    Get    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=true
    Response    test
```

Any ideas how to use this library?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311532/how-to-make-a-post-rest-api-in-robot-framework-with

Comment: @MarkHu It seems related but not similar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found another library which can do http calls and even parse json. Plus it's well documented http://peritus.github.com/robotframework-httplibrary/HttpLibrary.html.

Answer (score 14):

That library seems to be poorly documented. Perhaps you should take a look at https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests, which seems to be documented and maintained.

Answer (score 8):

REST Library for Robot Framework is not developed since 2009 (see [changes](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-restlibrary/source/list)).

Robot Framework official page references several HTTP level [testing libraries](http://robotframework.org/#libraries), as for example:

- [robotframework-requests](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests) - Development is active and uses Requests HTTP python library.

  Example Usage:

  ```
  Grab Avatar Url
           Create Session    github    https://api.github.com     
    ${resp}=
      ...  Get Request       github    /users/jandias
           Should Be Equal As Strings
             ...             ${resp.status_code}  200     
           Dictionary Should Contain Key
             ...             ${resp.json()}       avatar_url
  ```
- [robotframework-httplibrary](https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary) - Uses WebTest (with livetest) python library...

Comment: When the above code is run, there is an error coming saying `No keyword with name 'Create Session' found.`

Comment: @Rao: That seems to mean your robot is not identifying `Create Session` keyword. Notice the example is under _robotframework-requests_ library usage and that it is not a full test suite. That `Create Session` keyword is from this library. When using (not builtin) libraries under Robot you must **declare it**. I must guess that you probably skipped/forgot it. There are multiple ways of doing that, including in other robot files.

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful for others, another lib https://pypi.org/project/RESTinstance/, for testing RESTful JSON APIs

Answer (score -1):

use 'requests' library.
In Your RIDE tool, Open 'Library' & enter 'requests' and save.
Execute your test case.Hopefully it will work for you

Comment: This does not answers the question, neither you provided descriptive answer, you could have provided your suggestion in comments not in answers