# How to make a POST (ReST) API in Robot framework with

Tags: python, http, robotframework

I need to replicate the below API call in Robot Framework:

`curl -X POST "http://xyz/api/createApp" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @/tmp/testfile.json`

testfile.json has a json payload. I cannot send the content of Json file as body.

I have imported the HTTP libraries. But do not see any key-word to make an API call with file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/#Post has files parameter. And what you could do is use `Get File` keyword from OperatingSystem library and pass that to your Post keyword.

Answer (score 10):

Bulkan's robotframework-requests is nice. But if you can get by with less, you can do your own local lib/posthttp.py in a few lines like this:

```py
import requests
import json

def do_requests_post( url=None, data=None, headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}):
    return requests.post( url, data=data, headers=json.loads(headers) )

def do_requests_request( method="GET" url=None, data=None, headers={}):
    return requests.request( url, method=method, data=data, headers=json.loads(headers))
```

Note that the return object is the rich-and-powerful "Response" which has member functions like `.json()` (which returns a dict if the `.text` is sensed to be JSON) and `.status_code` (int).

Comment: Notes: 1) this mini-lib leaves things like cookies to the reader; 2) the only reason you can't call Requests directly from RF is because RF's auto-magic case-munging conflates requests.Request object and request.request() function.

Answer (score 0):

It perfectly works when using double backslashes and quotes like:

curl -i -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d "{\"target\" : \"5142221345\",\"source\" : \"432567890\",\"messages\" : [    {    \"format\" : \"AMR\", \"data\" : \"binarydata...\"    } ]}" http://10.4.4.11:8089/v1/voice/add

Comment: That's gross. Enclose the JSON in single-quotes, instead of escaping all the double-quotes.