# Testing REST APIs which use OAuth 2.0 using robot framework

Tags: rest, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, robotframework

How do we test RESTful APIs which use OAuth 2.0 using robot framework?

Do we have any keywords available? So far I have used HTTP Basic authentication which is very simple.

Please let me know if there is already have implementation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any general-purpose HTTP Requests calls or libs to do OAuth, as long as you set the credentials in the `Authorization` header. See [How to make a POST (ReST) API in Robot framework with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311532/how-to-make-a-post-rest-api-in-robot-framework) for more info.