# How to use Robot framework for Rest Automation with XML Body and XML Response Body

Tags: xml, rest, robotframework

I have used Rest Assured for Rest Automation using XML body and XML Response.

I have also used Robot framework for web UI automation using selenium2Library.

But now my requirement is to do Rest Automation using robot.

I came across HttpLibrary but it does not give me an option to use XML body in the request and specify content-type and read Response XML.

I used XML library for parsing xml but that is also not helpful.

Can someone help me in setting this up with some example and best way of achieving this.

An early response will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Note I went to [How to use REST library in Robot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910709/how-to-use-rest-library-in-robot-framework) but this is again not helpful to me as I am not using JSON for body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Requests library](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests), which is a keyword library built on top of the python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.  With it, you can make all of the normal REST calls (GET, PUT, etc). The library doesn't really care if the inputs and outputs are JSON, XML, or anything else (though it does include a convenience function for converting the results to a JSON object).

It doesn't have any features specifically for XML, robot comes with an [XML library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html) built in, which you can use to manipulate the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bryan for prompt response. I am trying it but it is complaining me for Non existing index or alias. I am not sure what am i suppose to give alias as.                                                                    **20151007 23:39:37.685 :  FAIL : Non-existing index or alias 'httpbin'.
Ending test:  **

Comment: The alias is anything you want. It's just a name for the connection (because you can have multiple connections open at once.

Comment: It worked, now I am working on getting the response body as xml, but it is returning me only the response code. Any help on that would be appreciated as well. I dont see any example for xml too.

Comment: What keyword are you using Atishay?

Comment: Hi Shicky, I am using POST it was working when I accepted, but then it is not working now. I am getting a lot of python errors, I am not good with python. All I want to do is read an xml file for which I use Get Binary data and then post it by creating connection using content type but its all stuck